# Is this site a good place for "can someone explain this paper to me in approachable language" style questions?

Tags: discussion

I have been browsing lots of those lately, many that apparently manage realtime framerates for things such as fully shadowed volumetric textures, impostors, etc., or multiple bounce global illumination, all on GPUs 5+ years old, but a lot of it flies far above my head, and, as much as I hate to admit it, I don't have the mental resources for understanding all of it myself, at the moment. Is computergraphics.stackexchange.com the right place to ask people to read, understand, and explain such things to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the scope of a paper. Possibly a short paper might come to a question. It would be better if you would ask something more specific than explain this paper for me.

There is nothing wrong with adding a paper you have been reading as a resource. Problem is that a paper might reference to many other prerequisites.

In any case in my experience it takes a few readings, at different days, to get a paper.

Comment: Apart from anything else, it's hard to explain something abstract without knowing what precisely you don't understand. If you ask, "How does this algorithm work?" the paper is already the answer to that. If you ask, "How might I use the algorithm in this situation?" that's something more specific and answerable.

Comment: @DanHulme Good point. We actually had one question that went back and forth like that already,